# JQuery UI Saving Sortable List

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I know this question has been asked before but the solutions did not work for me. I am trying to save the new ordering of items to the database.

I have simplified it very considerably but this is the basic idea of it. I have a form with a sortable list embedded in it.

```
<form id="itemlist">
    <ul id="itemsort">
       <li id="Item_1">Item<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID01"/></li>
       <li id="Item_2">Item<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID02"/></li>
       <li id="Item_3">Item<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID03"/></li>
       <li id="Item_4">Item<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID04"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I have JQuery and JQuery UI Loaded and the The Following code enables the sortable list function and posts the item ids and New sort order to a php script. the "editor" variable is a public variable that is set on load it works fine. The sorting works fine but the neworder value that posts doesn't seem to change when I re-order the list.

```
//sorting feature  
    $("#itemsort").live('hover', function() {
        $("#itemsort").sortable({ 
            opacity:.5,
            update : function () {          

                var neworder =  $('#itemsort').sortable('serialize');
                var inputs = serializePost('#itemlist');

                $.post("core/actions.php",{
                   'order': editor,
                   'inputs': inputs,
                   'neworder': neworder},function(){

                       alert("Order saved.", 1);

                });
            } 
        });
    });
```

On actions.php...

```
    if(isset($_POST['order'])){

            //set a variable for each post
            $batchid = $_POST['inputs']['itemid'];

            parse_str($_POST['neworder'], $neworder);

            //count the number of entries to be ordered
            $count = count($batchid);        

            //use the count to create an incremental loop for each item to be updated.
            $i=0;
            while ($i <= $count) {

   $query ="UPDATE {$_POST['order']} SET order=$neworder[item][$i] WHERE id=$batchid[$i]";
                ++$i;
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure why the order I get for each item will not change.

Any Ideas?

-L

Comment: Holy SQL Injection Vulnerability, Batman! `$query ="UPDATE {$_POST['order']} SET order=$neworder[item][$i] WHERE id=$batchid[$i]";` Your original question aside, this code is extremely dangerous. You need to make sure you're sanitizing your input variables before you pass them to a query, otherwise you might just find yourself in a world of hurt when someone ill-intentioned sets `$_POST['inputs']['itemid']` to `10 OR 1=1` or similar.

Comment: Yeah i know  sorry, That's just the simplest example of what I'm trying to do. I actually use classes and abstraction layers to protect my methods from injection. I didn't want to try and explain all the classes and parent classes etc. Hopefully it still makes enough sense to debug the logic in my actions.php script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#list").live('hover', function() {
        $("#list").sortable({

            update : function () {

                var neworder = new Array();

                $('#list li').each(function() {    

                    //get the id
                    var id  = $(this).attr("id");
                    //create an object
                    var obj = {};
                    //insert the id into the object
                    obj[] = id;
                    //push the object into the array
                    neworder.push(obj);

                });

                $.post("pagewhereyouuselist.php",{'neworder': neworder},function(data){});

            }
        });
    });
```

Then in your PHP file, or in this example "pagewhereyouuselist.php"

```
$neworderarray = $_POST['neworder'];
//loop through the list of ids and update your db
foreach($neworderarray as $order=>$id){    
    //you prob jave a connection already i just added this as an example
    $con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");

    if (!$con){
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET order = {$order} WHERE id = {$id}");
    mysql_close($con);

}
```

that should do it
i didn't test it as it is an example connection. the actual script I am actually using is more specific to my program this is a simplified version to show the concept

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

Your HTML fields

```
<form id="itemlist" method="POST">
    <ul id="itemsort">
        <li id="Item_1">Item 1<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID01"/></li>
        <li id="Item_2">Item 2<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID02"/></li>
        <li id="Item_3">Item 3<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID03"/></li>
        <li id="Item_4">Item 4<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="itemsRowID04"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

JS to send order:

```
$("#itemsort").live( 'hover', function() {
    $("#itemsort").sortable({
        update: function () {          
            var inputs = $('#itemlist').serialize();
            $.post("./jq-ui-test.php", inputs, alert("Order saved.") );
        } 
    });
});
```

Saving order:

```
if( isset( $_POST['itemid'] ) && is_array( $_POST['itemid'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['itemid'] as $order => $item ) {
        $order = intval( $order );
        $item_esc = mysql_real_escape_string( $item );
        $sql_query = "UPDATE {$_POST['order']} SET order={$order} WHERE id = '{$item_esc}'";
    }
}
```

Also, if you want that start order start from 1 ( not from 0 ) change `$order = intval( $order );` to `$order = intval( $order ) + 1;`

Comment: So is this just trying to use the items position in the itemid array of row ids so set its position in the DB? I can't seem to get it to work. When your serialize the itemlist does it use the original HTML layout or the new adjusted one via the javascript?

Comment: It seems to use the order of the original HTML and not the order of the sorted...maybe serializing the sorted items like before instead?

Comment: I still Can't get it to work. The order of the serialized form ids does not reflect the order change by drag and drop. I'm pulling my hair out now....