# php mysql sort order. Change sort order with hyperlink (up/down arrows)

Tags: php, mysql

If I have 4 db rows, I want to be able to sort them using column 'position'.

id - name - position

```
1  - row1 -    1
2  - row2 -    2
3  - row3 -    3
4  - row4 -    4
```

I know how to sort with php SELECT SORT BY etc

But I want to be able to press a hyperlink which would swap positions.

```
Row   img     img
row1  (down)
row2  (up)    (down)
row3  (up)    (down)
row4  (up)
```

ie, Press up on row 2 would change row2 position -> 1 and would change row 1 position -> 2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do your want? Is it just a JavaScript you're interested in? Or PHP code + database structure for re-arranging data in a database table?

Comment: either, was after advice into what ppl thought was the best solution. If you have ideas pls let me know.

Comment: Understood, but the way you've put your question it seems like people are thinking this is a JavaScript/GUI question. You should re-phrase your question, emphasizing that your have a position column and want a solution to manipulate its value.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer in PHP?

Comment: @fruityp: I would like to send via ajax to update SQL

Comment: This question was initially about knowledge, how about you share the code you've already created and then we can expand from there.

Answer (score 0):

On the hyperlink, load a PHP page which takes a few parameters:

1. The id of the row you want to move up/down
2. The current position of the row you want to move up/down
3. The id of the row beneath/above the row you want to move
4. The current position of the row you want to move up/down
5. Whether you want to move up or down of the row you're moving (such as its id), and the current position, as well as the new position.

From this, you will know exactly what you need to do, and can fashion a query to swap these items in the database. After this is done, reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to use a javascript library that allows item reordering.
Check this out:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Once the user has finished reordering, you can save the current positions of all your elements.
Using this method allows the user to rearrange all the items as he likes without having to refresh the page each time he clicks on "Up" or "Down".

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. How would this save for the next time they visit the page.

Comment: After the user has finished ordering the items, he should click on a button/link to save the current order. On that event, you need to serialize the items and send them to the server.

Comment: If you need more info about saving the ordered items, I just found another question exactly about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list

Answer (score 0):

um
what about this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
@$group[] = $row['img'];
}

and call it
echo $group[1];
echo $group[3];
echo $group[0];
echo $group[2];
```

etc.
idk if this what you meant

Answer (score 0):

if you want to swap the position in the UI only, you can use javascript.

eg:

```
<div id="1" > <div id="data_1">data goes here for row1</div> </div>
<div id="2" > <div id="data_2">data goes here for row2</div> <a onclick="moveUp(2);"> UP</a> <a onclick="moveDown(2);"> Down</a></div>
<div id="3" > <div id="data_3">data goes here for row3</div> </div>

<script>
function moveUp(n){
  var m = n-1;
  var own_id = 'data_'+n;
  var new_id = 'data_'+m;
  var tmp_data = '';
  var own_data = $(own_id).innerHtml;
  if($(new_id) != 'undefined'){
    tmp_data = $(new_id).innerHtml;
    $(new_id).innerHtml = own_data;
    $(own_id).innerHtml = tmp_data;
  }

}

function moveDown(n){
  //same logic can be applied here
}
</script>
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem and you can try this kind of solution. http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-custom-list-order