# How to reorder the list box items in html via drag&drop

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have to change the order of the items in listbox via drag and drop.How can i make it possible?

Regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery's sortable http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
then with .post use php to update a sql dB to retain the order
[JQuery UI Saving Sortable List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list)

Answer (score 0):

Check this for HTML5 http://html5demos.com/drag or this for php + jquery
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/
and for simple jquery http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/