# Save order of items from jQuery sort to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to allow my users to sort some items with jQuery UI sort ( http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default )

I have added all required files and it's working. I have problem with saving that new order (array) in PHP.

```
$(function() {
 $(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
 });
var sorted = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "serialize", { key: "sort" } );
});
```

Question is: How to transport that array of IDs to PHP after submitting form?

Note: I am not very familiar with JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Why do you have nested `$(function() {`? Does it even work?

Comment: yep, that part works. Problem is with transsfering array

Comment: Maybe this could help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list

Comment: Are you trying to submit the array with the rest of a form, or with ajax? if ajax, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. If you want to submit data with a form, you can use a hidden textarea: see http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/php/hidden1.html

Comment: @Mooseman. I have no other fields, I just have "Save" button as submit form.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually have any other form elements except submit button, why not use Ajax instead?

Given html structure

```
<ul class="list">
    <li id="item_1">1</li>
    <li id="item_2">2</li>
    <li id="item_3">3</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
```

Here's how you "transport that array of IDs to PHP"

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('.list').sortable();

      $('#send').click(function(e) {

          var sorted = $('.list').sortable("serialize");

          $.get('http://www.yoururl.com', sorted, function(data) 
          {
               console.log(data);
          });

     });
});
```

The data can be accessed from a `$_GET` array

```
<?php

    print_r($_GET);

?>
```

Comment: Can you actually see the output of `print_r($_GET);` from console?