# Saving menu sorting position to backend

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

### Introduction

I currently use the jQuery `.sortable` function and it works like a charm. However this is only client side and I would like to store the new sorting position to the backend (mySQL database).

I store the sorting order using numerical field (and retrieved using SQL `ORDER BY`).

```
Menu text     Sorting ID
------------   ---------
Menu item #1 => 0
Menu item #2 => 1
Menu item #3 => 2
Menu item #4 => 3
```

### Current HTML code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #4</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Tinker.io link: http://tinker.io/b3f27

### The question

Now, how would I store the new position into the database? Adding an ID to the sortable and posting it back to a `php` script which would lookup both sorting positions and switch them over is what I would do but I'm looking forward for your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic idea is sending data using AJAX after update:

JS:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  update : function () {
      var items = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
    $.get("sort.php?"+items);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="s_1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #1</li>
  <li id="s_2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #2</li>
  <li id="s_3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #3</li>
  <li id="s_4" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Menu item #4</li>
</ul>
```

Here you need to set id to each LI, please see [working demo](http://tinker.io/b3f27/1)

PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

You can find more detailed answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list)