# Pass JQSortable lists as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQSortable and what i want to do is have a button that will onclick, call a function which would create an array containing the list in "#run"
A function like this:

```
function setup(order2){
window.data = [document.getElementById("instance")];
window.data.push (order2);
//ajax request
}
```

I've tried using a bunch of different things like declaring a variable globaly as window.data when the lists are updated and then pulling that variable, i've tried called the function itself to get the variable using return, neither of them seem to work

I started out with the answer on this thread: [JQuery UI Saving Sortable List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list) and since that alowed me to alert the variable i've been trying to get it to alert in other functions
currently what i have is:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#list, #run" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      stop: function setup ( event, ui ) {var order2 = $('#run').sortable('toArray'); return order2;}
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I've tried using the above method, i've tried with using "update" instead of "stop"

Can anyone shed some light on how i could get the variable "order2" from the jqsortable function into another function?

lists:

```
<ul id="list" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item1'>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item2'>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item3'>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item4'>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id='item5'>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="run" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='item6'>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='item7'>Item 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='item8'>Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='item9'>Item 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='item10'>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

managed to get it working:

```
var order2 = [];
function display(){
alert (order2);
}
$(function () {
    $( "#list, #run" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      stop: function setup ( event, ui ) {order2 = $('#run').sortable('toArray'); alert(order2);}
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

for some reason when i did this before it wasn't working, i must have messed something up with the function call
Sorry if i wasted anyone's time and thanks for all the help

Comment: Did you try with receive function? are you getting order2 values? Store it in hidden field and access it on server-side.

Comment: I tried with the receive function and it still wasn't working
I'll use the hidden field method, i didn't think of that, javascript isn't my thing

Comment: when are you  calling setup(order2) ?

Comment: I was calling it with a function like this:
    function display(order2){
    setup();
    window.data = [document.getElementById("instance")];
    window.data.push (order2);
    alert (window.data);
    }
And using a button to trigger the display function, i noticed when i use window.data variable it causes a delay when i actualy place the object that's being dragged

Instead of using a hidden field, would i be able to just pull the list items specificaly at the time the user clicks the button? something similar to getelementbyid?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post some more code because it somewhat confusing with your setup(order2)? If you are getting the correct value of order2 in your stop function? and I believe you want to grab all the values those are in the run list into array and pass it on server side using button click ! is that so? define  order2 this before calling sortable method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yog2411/JJcr8/3/ I created this and its getting all text in alert on Update function. You can convert it to array or you can split on server side! is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I managed to get it working, even though it was something i was trying earlier for some reason it started to work now
code posted above in question

Comment: so you defined it before calling the function and it started working! Happy Coding!