# Mvc4 persist order of Jquery sortable list items to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of Items that I want the user to sort using a Jquery sortable.
the structure of the items is like this:

```
public class SortableItems
{

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public byte? Priority   { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

in my view I render the sortable inside a form in the following way:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "TestController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitTest" }))
            {
                <ul id="sortable" style="padding:0px;">

                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <li class="ui-state-default">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.List[i].Code, new { @class = "id" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.List[i].Priority, new { @class = "order" })
                            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
                            @Model.List[i].Name
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
                }
```

Now the user can sort the N items in the list to their hearts desire. But I have not found a way to update the pidden value for Priority (order of the items that the user has sorted)

How can I persist the order of the items to my controller?

Comment: There is no such thing as persisting data on controller. Do you mean saving the value the some persistent storage such as RDBMS ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi yes, I just need to get the order of the items to the controller, from there I can save everything to the database easily.

Comment: You'll needto do this via an ajax update as the data is dynamic and no longer bears relation to the order that it was plonked onto the form at request time. I've succesfully done this before, but am in transit justnow. I'll update with an answer that will help you within the next hour or so. Sorry not tohave the example to handbut you'll maybe discover the approach in the interim

Comment: In fact, did a quick search. The following is the guts of the appraoch in jquery (ignorethe php lpart obvs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342727/jquery-ui-saving-sortable-list?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I managed to solve the problem:

on the client side I did the following:

```
var neworder = new Array();

$("#sortable").disableSelection();


$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        neworder = new Array();
        $('#sortable li').each(function () {
            //get the id
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            neworder.push(id);
        });
    }
});


$(function () {
    $('#submitTest').submit(function () {

        if (neworder.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "GuardarPrioridad", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { orden: neworder.toString() },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ShowResultHere').text(result);
                $("#submitTest").hide();//  .tex.html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

each time the user moves an element I update an array that conatins the IDs of the elements in the order that the user put them in.

I then submit this array via ajax and it is recieved by the controller.

and my controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult SavePriority(string orden)
{
  string[] data= orden.Split(',');

   for (int i = 0; i < droguerias.Length; i++)
  {
   //save to DB

  }
  return Json("Saved!");
}
```